# Azure Data Factory v2 - SSIS lift and shift

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm in the process of evaluating the possibilites of lifting and shifting my ssis packages to ADFv2 but without testing I'm finding it hard to see if all SSIS functionalities are supported. 
For example my package unzips files, modifies contents of files (script task) saving new version in different directory, loads modified files to DB and update data etc

What I'm not sure about is unzipping the files (I dont want to transfer unzipped files from on prem) and also modifying files with script task. I believe these would have to be moved outside of SSIS and created as an activity of ADF? And leave only the load of files, updating data etc as my SSIS package? Probably with the files stored in Blob storage?

Or can all this still be done directly in SSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you currently do using SSIS on premises, you could also do using SSIS in ADF.  For example, you could install additional (un)zip programs using custom setup and utilize the %TEMP% folder/current working directory (".") of your SSIS IR to modify files, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-files-file-shares?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi Sandy, with the above links I managed to set it up. Question: how do I view %TEMP% folder/current working directory (".") of my SSIS IR nodes?